# How to find the 'outline' of a (concave) graph in 2D plane?

Tags: algorithm, convex-hull, planar-graph

I have a connected graph in 2D plane composed of some vertices and some edges defined between them. The overall shape of the graph is not necessarily convex, i.e. the adjacent vertices on the convex hull are not always connected by an edge. Now is there an existing algorithm that finds the 'outline' of this graph? The issue that's troubling me the most is that this outline polygon may contain vertices that are not vertices in the original graph, but rather the intersection of two edges, so I'm not quite sure how to deal with it...

Thanks!

Niko

Comment: Add points at the intersections and walk the perimeter of that.

Comment: (incidentally, if your graph has intersections like this, it's not necessarily planar; did you mean that the graph is *embedded* in the plane?)

Comment: Yes the edges can intersect. Sorry for the inaccurate use of terms...

Comment: How is this graph drawn in 2D being represented? Do you just have a list of edges and vertices? Do your vertices have coordinates? What data do you have to work with?